# Enaml examples from Enthought not working with Python(x,y) Enthought Tool Suite version of Enaml

Tags: python, enthought, pythonxy, epd-python, traitsui

I recently discovered Enaml, a Python GUI development package from Enthought.  I'm very interested in using it with Enthought Traits and Chaco for more rapid scientific application development.  I've been using Python(x,y) as my base Python installation because I like Spyder (familiar coming from Matlab background) my initial ambition was to build a PyQt application.

Python(x,y) comes with Enthought Tool Suite which seems to contain most of Enthought's internally developed tools like Traits, Chaco, Mayavi, and Enaml.  I saw the [pygotham slides](http://blog.enthought.com/?cat=157) on enaml and found the [tutorial examples](http://docs.enthought.com/enaml/instructional/tut_hello_world.html) which looks really cool!  When I try to run the first example, however, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bnables\Documents\Python\enaml\person.py", line 8, in 
    from enaml.stdlib.sessions import simple_session
ImportError: No module named sessions

I just figured out that my brand new installation of Python(x,y) 2.7.3.1 has Enthought Tool Suite version 4.2 and Enaml version 0.2... the online Enaml documentation is up to version 0.6.3.  So I guess my question is - what's the best path for a Python(x,y) user to use Enaml?

I was trying to avoid using Enthought Python Distribution outright, because I'm using this at work and do not have the authority or funding to purchase the paid version.  Can the Enthought Tool Suite built into Python(x,y) be updated from the Enthought source repositories?  Can Enaml itself be updated individually?

Enthought folks, I'm taking you up on your recent proclamation of officially supporting Stack Overflow questions! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used python(x,y), but I would assume you can build a project from source. This is probably the best course of action right now. We are putting a lot of efforts into Enaml which has the disadvantage of making it rapidly changing. It is not surprising that the version 0.2 doesn't run some of the examples from pygotham.

FYI, EPDFree now allows to update packages including Enaml. But considering the number of commits to Enaml everyweek, I would still recommend building from source even with EPD for another few months just to get all the cool features going in.

See we are delivering on our promise to monitor SO :).

Jonathan

Comment: Just realized I never marked this as the answer...
It's worth noting that this question and answer are probably both somewhat dated as EPD has been replaced by Enthought's "Canopy" python distribution and Enthought Tool Suite (ETS) now comes with a higher version of ENAML. Python(x,y) also now includes a higher version of ETS and ENAML.  Haven't tested anything recently, however.